# Pentaho BI Server - mysql type blob appears as a set of numbers

Tags: pentaho

I'm running Pentaho BI Server and added a mysql data source. 
I've managed to get a few reports working with simple tables but I'm having a problem with columns with data type - blob.

When a column of a "blob" data type is used in the report it just shows up as number and not text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess that the simple answer to all this in my cause was to change the "blob" datatype to "text". Since I was not using the "blob" to store any binary.

Answer (score 0):

A blob is a Binary Large OBject. So it is binary garbage as far as text printing is concerned. In PRD, blobs are returned as byte-array, and when printed (with the latest version of PRD) arrays are split into their components (bytes here) and printed as comma-separated list.

BLOBs have their uses if you want to transfer binary objects around. They can be used if you store images in your database and the image-field will happily read that image and display it properly.

If you have huge amounts of text stored in your database, a CLOB is more what you need.